# Assert doesn't work with FosUserBundle

Tags: forms, symfony, assert

I'm trying to custom the register validation of form user Register,

but the annoations in User Entity doesn't work.

part of User.php

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    private $name;
```

part of RegistrationFormType.php

```
        $builder
        ->add('name','text',array('required' => false,'validation_groups' => array('registration');
```

Part of RegisterController.php *( /var/www/Symfony/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Controller )*

```
$form = $formFactory->createForm(array(), null, array('validation_groups' => array('Registration', 'Default')));
```

When i click on form submit button with name blank field, nothing happening,  no validation message.

Comment: A stupid question: Do you add `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` in your entity class?

Comment: yes, there are `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` in User.php

Comment: And do you have a `configureOptions` method in your FormType?

Comment: yes,     `public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->class,
            'intention'  => 'registration',
        ));
    }`

Comment: Try basically with `$builder->add('name', 'text')`.

Comment: I'm just trying with : `public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'validation_groups' => array('registration', 'Default')
        );
    }` but nothing happening...

Comment: As far as I know validation groups are case sensitive so `registration` and `Registration` are different groups.

Comment: @scoolnico => i had try with just  $builder->add('name', 'text'), there are a HTML5 validation message that appears (i don't want it), so i had try with `$builder->add('name','text',array('required' => false,'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
                                                'attr' => array('class' => 'input__registerbox')));`nothing happening.

Comment: @qooplmao => i just check with `grep -r Registration . ` on my Bundle it's ok. everythig is `registration` no pb case sensitive

Comment: But the validation group that FOSUserBundle uses are "Registration" and "Default", by default.

Comment: @qooplmao i just moved registration ta Registration, nothing again! I never use Assert without FosuserBundle... i'will try and come back..